# Output rss feed in a list?

Tags: rss

I have a link to an rss (latest topics in a forum) and I'd like to output a list of the top 5 latest topics in the footer of my site. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: A list of top 5 latest topics seems to mix 2 things, popularity and freshness. How should that be combined? To get an answer include more details, like what forum software are you using what programming language and what have you come up with.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String[] from = new String[] { NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};//this is your text or feed title to be shown
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1};//will show the title in text1.
```

// Now create an array adapter and set it to display using your xml file(notes_row here)
   SimpleCursorAdapter notes =new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, c, from, to);
        setListAdapter(notes);
all this is under on create method.

Answer (score 1):

to add more than two things you can use custom adapter or can make another class that will extend simplecursoradapter to see code check [this](http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Creating-Lists-Using-The-Android-Listactivity/3/)